# jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, haml

I'm trying to create an appointment scheduler using jQuery (UI), Haml, and Rails. I'm making a set of tabs for the next 4 weeks.

```
#schedule
  %ul
    - @schedule.each_index do |i|
      %li
        %a{:href => "#schedule-#{i}"} #{@schedule[i][:week_range]}
  - @schedule.each_index do |i|
    %div{:id => "#schedule-#{i}"}
      %p test
```

Ideally, this would create a set of tabs such as (December 27th-January Nth) as the tab title and then have "test" in each box.

In applications.js I have:

```
$('#schedule').tabs();
```

However, this doesn't render properly and when I click on a tab it gives me this error in the javascript console:

```
jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.
```

I'm using the latest jQuery and jQuery UI releases.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is what the corresponding HTML looks like:

```
<div id='schedule'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href='#schedule-0'> December 27 - January 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#schedule-1'> January 3 - January 9</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#schedule-2'> January 10 - January 16</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#schedule-3'> January 17 - January 23</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id='#schedule-0'>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div id='#schedule-1'>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div id='#schedule-2'>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div id='#schedule-3'>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your generated HTML look like?

Comment: I'm calling the `$('#schedule').tabs();` inside of `$(document).ready(function() {...});`, so I think so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `id`s should not have a `#` in them in the generated HTML.  Change `%div{:id => "#schedule-#{i}"}` to `%div{:id => "schedule-#{i}"}`