# jQuery UI Tabs giving a 'Mismatching fragment identifier' error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

While trying to implement some jQuery UI Tabs using AJAX I keep running into this error in Firebug: `uncaught exception: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier`

Relevant HTML here:

```
<h1>AJAX Tabs</h1>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="chap1.htm">Chapter 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="chap2.htm">Chapter 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="chap3.htm">Chapter 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Relevant jQuery here:

```
$(init);

function init() {  
$("#tabs").tabs();  
}//end init
```

There seem to be other people who run into the [same](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/uncaught-exception-jquery-ui-tabs-mismatching-fragment-identifier-5-2-2010) [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4543557/982259), but they seem to have other problems with their pages or are implementing tabs in very different ways.

According to Firebug, the first request seems to run and the response is received, but the requested snippet is not then displayed. Afterwards, any other AJAX requests just receive the error above.

I do notice that although I defined the links as discreet HTML snippets, they seem to get treated like objects by jQuery.

Other than that I am totally in the dark as to what the cause of the problem is or how I would go about repairing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using an old version of jQuery-ui library (1.7.2)

jQuery UI 1.7.2 is not supported with jQuery 1.4.x. and above (you have 1.6.4)

please update both jQuery and jQuery-ui libraries to latest release

http://jquery.com/

http://jqueryui.com/home

Comment: oops. Sorry i was using the new version of jQuery but a older version of jQuery UI with the book i am using. I did not realize there would be a conflict. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end of id="tabs" -->
```

Give your attention to close tag (`<!-- end of id="tabs" -->`) of  the last div. Maybe you are missing close tag or you are implementing it wrong place. It should be at the end of "container divs" (`<div id="tabs-1">,<div id="tabs-2">,<div id="tabs-3">`) not the end of "ul".

Answer (score 0):

Re: Irishka

actually, jQueryUI 1.7.2 is dependent on jQuery 1.3.2 and above - so that likely isn't the problem.

check to see if everything you have specified in your "tabs" div has an associated content div, i.e. this:

```
<h1>AJAX Tabs</h1>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="chap1.htm">Chapter 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="chap2.htm">Chapter 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="chap3.htm">Chapter 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="chap1.html"> Content here </div>
    <div id="chap2.html"> Content here </div>
    <div id="chap3.html"> Content here </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### I had a similar error. To get rid of it helped to write the attribute *role* in the *div* with the values: *tabpanel* and *tab*.

```
<div id="tabs" role="tabpanel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1" role="tab">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2" role="tab">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3" role="tab">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel">
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2" role="tabpanel">
            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3" role="tabpanel">
            <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
            <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```